# play adobe flash on a splash screen

Tags: android

```
Android Studio 0.5.1
```

Hello,

I have created a flash animation using adobe flash. I would like to show this on a splash screen while the user is waiting for the app to load.

Does Android have any player that will play the flash *.flv files?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Flash is not supported anymore in Android so it is better to convert your video to mp4 or other format.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use splash screens in Android. It gives a poor UX.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html